# Pluralization of multi-word scaffold name in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a Rails application in Italian, but I'm having troubles with pluralization.
I have a model named "Distintivo", which I can correctly pluralize as "Distintivi" and a model named "Socio", which I can correctly pluralize as "Soci", but I need another model to make a join table. I'd like to call this model "DistintivoSocio" and pluralize it as "DistintiviSoci", but when I generate the scaffold Rails chooses distintivo_soci, ignoring my inflections.rb, that goes like this:

```
inflect.irregular 'distintivo',       'distintivi'
inflect.irregular 'socio',            'soci'
inflect.irregular 'distintivo_socio', 'distintivi_soci'
```

I also tried with

```
inflect.irregular 'distintivosocio',  'distintivisoci'
```

but I got no luck. Any ideas?

Sorry if Italian grammar is weird.

Comment: My assumption is that the scaffold behaviour is to select `first.singular_second.plural` as opposed to `(first_second).plural`, as the join model is multiple links between singular first and second instances.

Comment: Why do you want have a class `DistintivoSocio`? Rails usually does not need such a model for `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations.

Comment: I believe [this](http://blog.flatironschool.com/post/35346328762/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many) post explains quite well why we chose to use a model instead of a has_and_belongs_to_many association.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters when one inflection is included in other. Try:

```
inflect.irregular 'distintivo_socio', 'distintivi_soci'
inflect.irregular 'distintivo',       'distintivi'
inflect.irregular 'socio',            'soci'
```